# wso2 das purging configuration - not work?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

> WSO2DAS version : 3.0.1

I set up WSO2DAS after reviewing Minimum High Availability Deployment document.
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1)

and DAS product using mariaDB. 
mariaDB have two databases (WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB, WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB)
table in database have data after request api.

finally. I set up purging configuration after reviewing Purging Data document.
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Purging+Data)

Changed the configurations within the   property  as shown below.

```
<analytics-dataservice-configuration>
   <!-- The name of the primary record store -->
   <primaryRecordStore>EVENT_STORE</primaryRecordStore>
   <!-- Analytics Record Store - properties related to record storage implementation -->
   <analytics-record-store name="EVENT_STORE">
      <implementation>org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore</implementation>
      <properties>
            <property name="datasource">WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB</property>
            <property name="category">large_dataset_optimized</property>
      </properties>
   </analytics-record-store>
   <analytics-record-store name = "PROCESSED_DATA_STORE">
      <implementation>org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore</implementation>
      <properties>
            <property name="datasource">WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB</property>
            <property name="category">large_dataset_optimized</property>
      </properties>
   </analytics-record-store>
   <!-- The data indexing analyzer implementation -->
   <analytics-lucene-analyzer>
    <implementation>org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer</implementation>
   </analytics-lucene-analyzer>
   <!-- The number of index data replicas the system should keep, for H/A, this should be at least 1, e.g. the value 0 means
        there aren't any copies of the data -->
   <indexReplicationFactor>1</indexReplicationFactor>
   <!-- The number of index shards, should be equal or higher to the number of indexing nodes that is going to be working,
        ideal count being 'number of indexing nodes * [CPU cores used for indexing per node]' -->
   <shardCount>6</shardCount>
   <!-- The amount of index data (in bytes) to be processed at a time by a shard index worker. Minimum value is 1000. -->
   <shardIndexRecordBatchSize>20971520</shardIndexRecordBatchSize>
   <!-- The interval in milliseconds, which a shard index processing worker thread will sleep during index processing operations. This setting
        along with the 'shardIndexRecordBatchSize' setting can be used to increase the final index batched data amount the indexer processes
        at a given time. Usually, higher the batch data amount, higher the throughput of the indexing operations, but will have a higher latency
        of record insertion to indexing. Minimum value of this is 10, and a maximum value is 60000 (1 minute). -->
   <shardIndexWorkerInterval>1500</shardIndexWorkerInterval>
   <!-- Data purging related configuration -->
   <analytics-data-purging>
      <!-- Below entry will indicate purging is enable or not. If user wants to enable data purging for cluster then this property
       need to be enable in all nodes -->
      <purging-enable>true</purging-enable>
      <cron-expression>0 50 11 * * ?</cron-expression>
      <!-- Tables that need include to purging. Use regex expression to specify the table name that need include to purging.-->
      <purge-include-tables>
         <table>.*</table>
         <!--<table>.*jmx.*</table>-->
      </purge-include-tables>
      <!-- All records that insert before the specified retention time will be eligible to purge -->
      <data-retention-days>365</data-retention-days>
   </analytics-data-purging>
</analytics-dataservice-configuration>
```

As a result of checking in DAS carbon portal ORG_* tables data was deleted after purging time. 
But two databases (WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB, WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB) data remaining.

**The question is:**

is purging configuration cover ORG_* tables?
Or is the setting wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Could you please clarify what you mean by

> But two databases (WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB, WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB) data remaining.

Do you mean that you can still see tables in the databases? If yes, then it is by design. DAS data purging only deletes records older than the specified time, it does not delete the tables themselves.